# Insert an array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am handling a Javascript function to have a behaviour below:

1/ When the checkbox button is checked, an array of setting strings is inserted into another array

```
var RB_array_1=[];
var mycheckboxButton1 = document.getElementById('mycheckboxButton1');
if (mycheckboxButton.checked===true) {
  RB_array_1=["setting A_1","setting B_1"]
}
```

2/ It will insert into another array while it remain the array inside previously:

```
const final_array = 
  [ RB_array_1
  , RB_array_2
  , ...
  , RB_array_x
  ]
```

and it should remain array inside the array:

```
const final_array = 
  [ [ 'setting A_1', 'setting B_1'] 
  , [ 'setting A_2', 'setting B_2'] 
  , ...
  , [ 'setting A_x', 'setting B_x'] 
  ]
```

Is there any way to insert an array into another array ?

Comment: `final_array.push(RB_array_1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for the `push` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [4,5,6];
const arrs = [arr1];

arrs.push(arr2);

console.log(arrs);
```

Answer (score 1):

`RB_array_1.push(["setting A_1","setting B_1"])`

just make sure whatever you push inside your final array element also has to be an ARRAY. Should work fine according to me.

[Refer this for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHjH7.png)